# Getting KeyError while merging dataframe even though columns are correct

Tags: python, pandas, merge, keyerror

I am trying to merge two dataframes but keep getting KeyError.
I checked column names I used and it looks fine. I even trimmed the col names so that there is no leading or trailing space. Still I get the same error.
I have no clue why is it failing.
Can someone help me with this? I went through lot of posts here and in other sites but none seems to fix my issue.
This is the merge statement:

```
roaster_ilc_mrg = (pd.merge(roaster,ilcdata,left_on="Emp ID", right_on="Emp Serial"))
```

Here is the cols from both df:

```
roaster Columns:  Index(['Emp ID', 'XID', 'Name', 'Team', 'Location', 'Site', 'Status'], dtype='object')
ilcdata Columns:  Index(['Activity Code', 'Billing Code', 'Emp Serial', 'Emp Lastname',
       'Emp Manager', 'Weekending Date', 'Total hours'],
      dtype='object')
```

Error I see:

```
File "C:\Abraham\Python\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 1563, in _get_label_or_level_values
    raise KeyError(key)

KeyError: 'Emp Serial'
```

ilcdata.head() data
[image]

if I do below check for any column lables in ilcdata dataframe, i get default value ie, 'No col'

```
print(ilcdata.get('Emp Serial', default='No col'))
```

But all those labels are present there...Its driving me crazy coz I have used similar merge before and it was working smoothly

Comment: try to put "Emp ID" in a list like this ["Emp ID"].

Comment: I tried that as well..

Comment: try this roaster.merge(ilcdata,....) as well.

Comment: tried now...still getting same error

Comment: could you remove () around pd.merge?

Comment: done..same result..

Comment: You need to double-check your `ilcdata` dataframe, reconstituting them from your column names gives no KeyError.

Comment: Last try: could you print the names of column by list(df.columns)?

Comment: list(df.columns) result--
ilcdata Columns:  ['Activity Code', 'Billing Code', 'Emp Serial', 'Emp Lastname', 'Emp Manager', 'Weekending Date', 'Total hours']

Comment: I hope this work:  pd.merge(roaster,ilcdata, on=["Emp ID", "Emp Serial"] )

Comment: no..now it shows KeyError for "Emp ID"

Comment: @Cimbali, did you mean, try to fetch data from that df like this: 
print(ilcdata['Emp Serial'])
This works and I see data..

Comment: Update your post with `ilcdata.head(5)` please.

Comment: added df head data in original post..